# How to apply blur effect to bitmap in onLoadingComplete of universal-image-loader?

Tags: android, bitmap, universal-image-loader, renderscript

I need to apply blur effect to bitmap downloaded via `universal-imageloader`
but crashes and in logs I got such message:

//    4508-4564/com.sample A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2, fault addr 0x9c4e9000 in tid 4564 (com.sample)
//            07-18 19:49:20.019    4508-4570/com.sample A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2, fault addr 0x9c4e9000 in tid 4570 (com.sample)
//            07-18 19:49:20.019    4508-4569/com.sample A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2, fault addr 0x9c4e9000 in tid 4569 (com.sample)
//            07-18 19:49:20.019    4508-4565/com.sample A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2, fault addr 0x9c4e9000 in tid 4565 (com.sample)

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoaderInstances.initGeneralImageLoader();
imageLoader.loadImage(fileName,new SimpleImageLoadingListener(){
    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
cropedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(loadedImage, 0, 0, loadedImage.getWidth() / 2, loadedImage.getHeight());
        imageView.setImageBitmap(blurBitmap(cropedBitmap));
    }
});



   private Bitmap blurBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap outBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(getContext());
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur blurScript = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    Allocation allIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bitmap);
    Allocation allOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outBitmap);
    blurScript.setRadius(25.f);
    blurScript.setInput(allIn);
    blurScript.forEach(allOut);
    allOut.copyTo(outBitmap);
    bitmap.recycle();
    rs.destroy();
    return outBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Can you try without MIPMAP_FULL?

Comment: It  gives the same result.
The interesting is that when I apply this method to bitmap that is from project resources it works as expected ,while for bitmaps downloaded via imageloader it causes problems

Comment: I am not familiar with imageloader. Can you point us to what exactly this is? Is it possible that imageloader is keeping the image in a format we don't support? Do you know what the image format is for this bitmap (i.e. RGBA8888, ....)?

Answer (score 0):

Add some logging to verify, or step through with the debugger, but I think the crash is likely happening at this line:

```
output.copyTo(blurredBitmap);
```

The `blurredBitmap` was created with 1/10 the width and height of the input bitmap. It's `Allocation` is the full size of the input bitmap.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what you're saying you did.

Comment: What is `croppedBitmap` and where does it come from?

Comment: I have edited . 
cropedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(loadedImage, 0, 0, loadedImage.getWidth() / 2, loadedImage.getHeight());

Comment: When I download the image via  browser and load bitmap  from app res/drawable it works as expected ,while applying  blur method to bitmap download via universal-imageloader it crashes.